# Webpacking firebase NativeScript

Tags: firebase, webpack, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I can't get the [firebase plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) to cooperate with webpack. I'm getting

> firebase is not defined

Firebase is wrapped in an angular service and I am initializing it in my first component. Solution mentioned on [github](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/289) didn't help me.
I am importing firebase like so:

```
import firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
```

And using it like so:

```
@Injectable
export class FirebaseService {

    initialize() {    
        firebase.init({
            ...
        })
    }
```

and in my component `this.firebaseService.initialize();`

This works fine without AOT, it's the last thing keeping me from going to production with my app.

Comment: Try using `import * as firebase from "nativescript-plugin-firebase"` instaed of require

Comment: That worked! Thanks, can you post is an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: as a side note, it will be even better to import only the method used and not the whole firebase module (valid for any other module in TS) e.g. `import { init } from "nativescript-plugin-firebase"` and the use it directly `init{{}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `import from` syntax (instead of `require`) will resolve this case

e.g.

`import * as firebase from "nativescript-plugin-firebase";`